# Describe the image of the region under the transformation: The disk $|z| < 1$ under $w =\frac{iz-i}{z+1} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Describe the image of the region under the transformation: The disk $|z| < 1$ under $w =\frac{iz-i}{z+1} $.

What I did is:

$$w =\frac{iz-i}{z+1} \Rightarrow z=\frac{w+i}{i-w}$$
$$|z|<1 \Rightarrow \left|\frac{w+i}{i-w}\right|=\frac{|w+i|}{|i-w|}<1 \Rightarrow |w+i|<|i-w|=|w-i|$$
Let $w=x+yi$, then
$$|x+(y+1)i|<|x+(y-1)i| \Rightarrow x^2+(y+1)^2<x^2+(y-1)^2 \Rightarrow y<0$$
Which means $f$ maps $|z|<1$ to $y<0$.

Did I get the idea correct? Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Strictly speaking you have only proven that $w(\{|z|<1\})$ is a subset of $\{y<0\}$, you need the other direction of implications to conclude equality.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Good point. To the OP: note that you have in fact equivalences between the steps, not just one-way implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good.

Alternative way to complete it without cartesian: $|w+i| \lt |w-i|$ $\iff |w+i|^2 \lt |w-i|^2$ $\iff (w+i)(\bar w - i) \lt (w-i)(\bar w +i)$ $\require{cancel} \iff \cancel{w \bar w} - i(w - \bar w) + \bcancel{1} \lt \cancel{w \bar w} + i(w - \bar w ) + \bcancel{1}$ $\iff 0 \lt 2i\cdot2i\operatorname{Im}(w)$ $\iff \operatorname{Im}(w) \lt 0\,$.

Comment: Thanks! So if there is a similar problem, like given the domain of $f$ and want to find the image. Could I apply the similar method?

Comment: @Nan Yes, except it may not always be as easy to work out the transformations both ways. Here for example, it helped a lot that $w(z)$ was an invertible function to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution. Notice that
$\frac{iz-i}{z+1} = i - \frac{2i}{z+1}$, so the transformation $z\mapsto w(z)$ is the combination $w(z) = w_4(w_3(w_2(w_1(z))))$ where:

1. $w_1(z) = z+1$ takes $|z|<1$ to $|z-1|<1$,
2. $w_2(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ takes $|z-1|<1$ to the half space ${x<1}$,
3. $w_3(z) = -2iz$ takes $x<1$ to the half space $y<1$,
4. $w_4(z) = z+i$ maps $y<1$ to $y<0$.